# Delphi estrutura if

Tags: delphi-7

Saudações, a todos

Este trecho de código faz parte de um outro que eu uso pra pra puxar textos externos concatenados é muita coisa e está funcionando, só que no projeto aqui quando em prena carga está levando 11 minutos pra terminar a execução, então estou tentando exugar o código pra ver se resolve e vai diminuindo este tempo.

Teria como enxugar este código aqui?

```
begin 
if StringGrid1.Cells[1,3]  ('')  then 
for i:=1 to 100 do memo40.Lines.add(StringGrid1.Cells[i,3]) 
end ;
```

```
begin 
if StringGrid1.Cells[1,4]  ('')  then 
for i:=1 to 100 do memo41.Lines.add(StringGrid1.Cells[i,4]) 
end ;
```

```
begin 
if StringGrid1.Cells[1,5]  ('')  then 
for i:=1 to 100 do memo42.Lines.add(StringGrid1.Cells[i,5]) 
end ;
```

```
begin if StringGrid1.Cells[1,6]  ('')  then 
for i:=1 to 100 do memo43.Lines.add(StringGrid1.Cells[i,6]) 
end ;
```

```
begin 
if StringGrid1.Cells[1,7]  ('')  then 
for i:=1 to 100 do memo44.Lines.add(StringGrid1.Cells[i,7])
end ;
```

```
begin 
if StringGrid1.Cells[1,8]  ('')  
then for i:=1 to 100 do memo45.Lines.add(StringGrid1.Cells[i,8]) 
end ;
```

```
begin 
if StringGrid1.Cells[1,9]  ('')  then 
for i:=1 to 100 do memo46.Lines.add(StringGrid1.Cells[i,9]) 
end ;
```

```
begin 
if StringGrid1.Cells[1,10] ('')  then 
for i:=1 to 100 do memo47.Lines.add(StringGrid1.Cells[i,10])
end ;
```

```
begin if StringGrid1.Cells[1,11] ('')  then 
for i:=1 to 100 do memo48.Lines.add(StringGrid1.Cells[i,11])
end ;
```

begin 
if StringGrid1.Cells[1,12] ('')  then 
for i:=1 to 100 do memo49.Lines.add(StringGrid1.Cells[i,12])
end ;

Comment: enqunto tava postando não se porque não apareceu o sinal  de diferença <>  tentei acertar , então todas as linhas todas estão neste formato                                                                                   if StringGrid1.Cells[x,y]<>  ('')  then

Answer (score 3):

```
memo40.Lines.BeginUpdate;
for j := 3 to 12 do
    if  StringGrid1.Cells[1, j]('') then
        for i := 1 to 100 do
            memo40.Lines.add(StringGrid1.Cells[i, j]);
memo40.Lines.EndUpdate;
```

É preciso declarar `j` junto de onde declara `i`.

O uso de `BeginUpdate` e `EndUpdate` deve aumentar substancialmente a velocidade da operação. Sem isso, o Delphi vai atualizar o elemento a cada nova linha que for adicionada, o que consome muito tempo desnecessariamente.

Comment: Havenard que bacana, agradecido 

ok pode deixar que vou declarar o J também, 

verdade mesmo, eu tava testando o programa em carga máxima mas tava consumindo muito tempo, que legal não conhecia esses dois comandos BeginUpdate e EndUpdate. 

Na semana que entra testo ele, e dou retorno, obrigado.

Comment: Havenard nossa diminuiu  bastante o tempo em plena carga caiu de 11 minutos pra 2 minutos. Muito agradeçido pela sua ajuda e atenção

Comment: @acs Talvez você consiga otimizar ainda mais usando `TStringBuilder` em vez de montar os dados diretamente no `TMemo.Lines`, mas pra isso você vai ter que pesquisar um pouco como usa. Eu não programo em Delphi a uns 15 anos.

Comment: Havenard obrigado vou pesquisar sim e agradeçido pela sua dica
Esse programa até agora foi todo escrito no Lazarus vou ver se tem pra ele se não vou ter que aguardar um pouco.   
tenho o delphi7, só que como o programa é muito grande daria muito trabalho transfrir o código do zero pra ele, porque tem muitos componetes e muitas referências entre eles e as variáveis.